# Comprehensive guide to install Ubuntu 12.10 x64 after Windows 7 on UEFI and GPT disk

Tags: windows-7, uefi, gpt

My laptop is currently running Windows 7 64-bit on a GPT disk. Instead of BIOS, the laptop also uses UEFI. After googling around, I cannot find any guide for this problem (maybe my googling skill is bad).

However, I just tried to install Ubuntu alongside with Windows 7 all by myself. After that, I couldn't boot to Windows. Luckily, I was able to fix that. Now, I want to find a guide to follow to make sure that there would be no problem.

EDIT 1: I found a guide here that suggests using Boot-Repair:
- If you want to try grub-efi, it is first necessary to have a GPT disk with an ESP (EFI partition= FAT32, >200Mo, start_of_the_disk, boot flag), and to setup the BIOS in EFI mode. Then you need to install grub-efi (an easy way for this is to use Boot-Repair with the "Separate /efi" option). To finish, some old EFI-BIOS need to create an entry that boots the grub*.efi file in the EFI partition.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2003442&page=2

However, I still don't understand that I must install Ubuntu first (with a partition ? and a swap partition ?) then use Boot-repair or Boot-repair first ?

Answer (score 0):

Installing on a UEFI system is not easy, but as a start you can [look at ChrUbuntu](http://chromeos-cr48.blogspot.com/2012/04/chrubuntu-1204-now-with-double-bits.html) (for Google Chromebook, which also uses EFI). Basically you'll need to get a boot disk of some kind to get up and running -- perhaps ChromeOS would help?

Comment: Documentation on dual-booting **Windows 7** and Ubuntu on an PC (32- or 64-bit) with UEFI is quite scarce. Most of the attention is on how secure boot (or whatever the right term is) should be dealt with in **Windows 8**.

Comment: That's correct.